# Motion blur creates random rotation of instanced objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I have fractured object in collection.
In Geo nodes those objects are instanced, applied some animated noise position.
In viewport everything look ok.
But in Cycles renderer each instance every nth frame randomly rotate for one frame and come back to position it should be.

When Motion Blur is off all instances behave normally.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by *Set Shade Smooth* in combination with *Motion Blur*.